# LINQ to entities comparing collections

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having issues with a Linq query that will actually do what I need it to.  I've constructed a search that needs to find articles in a database (entity framework) and the search then uses a list of checkboxes to allow the user to only search within certain areas of practice.  I've seen posts about linq joins & multiple collections, but my problem is that what I'm trying to select from is the parent table Article and I need to comppare the .Practices to a Practices list I've compiled from the checkbox list.

Before it was a checkbox list, it was a dropdown and this query worked to search for 1 practice:

```
ar = (from a in db.Articles
      from p in a.Practices
      where p.ID == practiceID
      select a);
```

Now, I need the where clause to work like an "IN" from regular SQL.  My collection of Practices compiled from a checkbox list need to be compared to db.Articles.Practices for my search.

Any suggestions or clarification needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming: List practiseIds

```
ar = (from a in db.Articles
  from p in db.Practices
  where practiseIds.Contains(p.ID)
  select a);
```

However some clarification is needed:

IN is not a first class supported SQL method in EF so the above code will in fact turn into a list of or's (this may have been resolved in the .net 4 release of EF - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/08/05/improvements-to-the-generated-sql-in-net-4-0-beta1.aspx)

Psuedo Code -

```
Select * From db.Articles 
inner join db.Practices on <relation>
Where db.Practices.practiceid = @p0 || db.Practices.practiceid = @p1 || etc..
```

Comment: Incidentally both should generate the same query plan in SQL

Comment: Both answers were identical... this one was first, so got the check.  Yes, that works... I'm new to Linq, so thanks from a noob.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass in the id collection as array `practiceIds` and use a `Contains()` query:

```
ar = (from a in db.Articles
      from p in a.Practices
      where practiceIds.Contains(p.ID)
      select a);
```

Comment: This will work as long as both collections are from the same query context. If `practiceIds` is in a memory context and `db.Articles` is pulling from a data context it will throw runtime exceptions. To counter that, the `ar` will need to have the where clause extracted and sent `ToList()`. Once it's an IEnumerable instead of an IQueryable the sequences can be compared with `.Where(x => practiceIds.Contains(x.ID))`.   +1 btw :)

Comment: @JoelEtherton: I had assumed its just a collection of primitives not connected to a data context at all - OP said he has a set of ids compiled from checkboxes

Comment: Even if it's primitives it'll throw this exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985622/linq-to-sql-exception-local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementati

Comment: Thanks, it works... i gave the other guy the check for answering first.  I had tried similar things, but not exactly that.  Take care.